# CSS3 HTML5 Slider Swipe

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have searched the net for different kinds of sliders, and swipe sliders.
The thing is i wanted to make a responsive swipe slider website for phones, a slider where-in you can swipe left and swipe right, but the thing is i want to make it as a full page swipe slider.

I want to use them as my pages.

Can someone give me an example of a full page swipe slider that can be available for phones?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to use jQuery, have a look at [slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). It is responsive and is does ship with touch support. You can easily set the amount of visible elements to 1 and use some CSS to make them 100% wide and high.

Comment: Does not work well on WP8.1.  WP8.1 uses swipe in the Browser for Back and Forward page functions.  When I swipe I end up back at the previous page I was on.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's the downside when using slides. But that's an UX problem, not the libraries fault. I have similar issues on Blackberry OS, but it usually works when starting the gesture in the center of the screen...

Comment: That may be why Slick does not hype that it works with mobile phones. I have not found a solution that overcomes / disables the UX swipe features.  Too many devices with to many issues.  Then there are the problems with Touch Events vs. Mouse Events. A nightmare app.

Comment: thank you guys for giving quick feedback about the Slick...,